# Compare two dates in a table and return the greater using SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, comparison

Both dates are stored in one table. If date1 is greater, I want to return date1, if date2 is greater I want to return date2. I want them to be part of larger query so I would like one main query but if that is not possible, I can use a temp table and use a second query afterward. The code will be executed in a stored procedure.

Comment: Let me guess, the dates are stored as VARCHAR(20)?

Comment: two date fields, actually I think i may use case statement, just didn't ponder much on this right now. I am using SQL 2008, sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It'll be a CASE statement in standard SQL

```
CASE WHEN date1 >= date2 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END
```

There are specific functions on some RDBMS that will do it like Excel does Max but this is standard...

Answer (score 2):

You could `SELECT GREATEST('1776-07-04', '1977-08-16')`. It should return the most recent date (not necessarily the best date).

Comment: not a standard function - DB2 does not have that function (you would use `MAX` instead, which appears to be a vendor specific use).  That said, if it belongs to your platform, it's well usable (I would use `MAX on DB2, even though it does make it less portable).

Comment: @X-Zero I weighed the pun versus the standard, and went for the pun.

Comment: Yeah, most of my stuff has gone with what turns out to be a vendor-specific function...  Ah well.