# two query results in datetime compare in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql queries.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FIRST_TABLE
FROM
    FIRST_TABLE
```

and

```
SELECT 
    DATE_SECOND_TABLE
FROM
    SECOND_TABLE
```

The above two queries may return single or multiple records.
    I need to check the second query results if any date value is greater than any of the date value of first query results then it will evaluate true.

I need some suggestion on this.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is somewhat like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630278/compare-two-dates-in-a-table-and-return-the-greater-using-sql

Comment: @mns . . . It would help if you added sample data and desired results.

Comment: @SohailxIN3N .. how it is similar .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select 'true'
from second_table
where date_second_table > (select max(date_first_table) from first_table)
```

The statement:  "I need to check the second query results if any date value is greater than any of the date value of first query results then it will evaluate true."  This is a bit hard to follow the logic.  The above returns 'true' when the values of the second query are greater than all the values of the first query.

The answer may be:

```
select max('true')
from second_table
where date_second_table > (select min(date_first_table) from first_table)
```

A key addition is the `max()` function, which turns this into an aggregation function so it returns one row.

EDIT:

Your question is ambiguous about what to do in the "false" case.  One answer, as you suggest in the comments is:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from second_table
where date_second_table > (select min(date_first_table) from first_table);
```

A similar approach is to use an explicit `join`.  Although this would perform less well, it may better capture the logic:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from first_table t1 join
     second_table t2
     on t1.date_first_table > t2.date_second_table;
```

Comment: will not work correctly. This will return true only if all data in second table is greater than maximum in first table. If second table has only one row value 2, but first table has 1 and 3 this query will not return true.

Comment: select CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
from second_table
where date_second_table > (select max(date_first_table) from first_table) ..here count = 1 means true and 0 means false..i think it will work.and in the second table if the date values are greater then max of first then it is greater than all dates of first table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ..can you please edit your answer.so that i can accept it.

Comment: CORRECTION : if any date values of second result set are greater than min of first result set then it will return 1 else return 0.That's what i want here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_SECOND_TABLE FROM SECOND_TABLE WHERE DATE_SECOND_TABLE > (SELECT DATE_FIRST_TABLE FROM FIRST_TABLE)
```

When you say "it will evaluate to true", you do mean it will return the result presumably

Comment: i mean i need to check all the records in the second result set and if any record having date value greater than any of records of the first result set, then the case statement will return true else return false